# Hierarchy and multiple option drop down list (HTML) and navigate between items (Child nodes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi :) i need to make HTML  hierarchy drop down list it consists of levels(options) and  each option if has child nodes we will see arrow beside it if we click on this arrow all this options will disappear and all child nodes will appear ..... and each one has an arrow beside it in left and another one in right if we click on left arrow all this options will disappear and parent level will appear  and if we click on right arrow the next level will appear and so on when i search about it i found tree drop down list but my manager don't want it :( ..... pleas if some one have any idea or link about this drop down i hop to till me ....thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/1jwyauLy/

```
<ul class="level1">
    <li> <span> &rarr; Option 1</span>

        <ul class="level2">
            <li> <span class="lar">&larr;</span> Option 1.1</li>
            <li> <span class="lar">&larr;</span> Option 1.2</li>
            <li> <span class="lar">&larr;</span> Option 1.3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <span>  &rarr; Option 2</span>

        <ul class="level2">
            <li> <span class="lar">&larr;</span> Option 2.1</li>
            <li> <span class="lar">&larr;</span> Option 2.2</li>
            <li> <span class="lar">&larr;</span> Option 2.3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span>  &rarr; Option 3</span>

        <ul class="level2">
            <li> <span class="lar">&larr;</span> Option 3.1</li>
            <li> <span class="lar">&larr;</span> Option 3.2</li>
            <li> <span class="lar">&larr;</span> Option 3.3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
$(".level2").hide();

$(".level1>li").on("click", function () {
    $(this).find(".level2").show();
    $(this).find(">span").hide();
    $(".level1>li").not(this).hide();
})

$(".lar").on("click", function () {
    $(".level1>li").show();
    $(".level2").hide();
    $(this).closest(".level2").prev("span").show();
    return false;
})
```

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your replay but how to include it as options on select tag ??!!